# Read HTML content from a WebView using WebDriver and Appium

Tags: android, selenium, webview, webdriver, appium

I am trying to automate Gmail App on android using Selenium WebDriver and Appium. I need to read an email content and then validate it. But the complete element is displayed as a single webview and I am I am unable to read any text from the email. Please suggest a way so that I can read the email content

Code Used:

```
package com.example.appium;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class GmailInvoke {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");

      //Gmail
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.google.android.gm");        
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ui.MailActivityGmail");

        WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
        List <WebElement> emails = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.FrameLayout"));
        emails.get(5).click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("com.google.android.gm:id/webview")).getText());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you well, you're trying to automate a hybrid app (native app that opens a webview). In this case you need to switch context to the webview context.
Please refer to appium's documentation:
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md

Answer (score 0):

I think that its impossible to automate pre-installed apps. I tried it too.